# Issues with installing OpenSUSE from DVD on Simics

Tags: simics

I'm trying to follow Getting Started's installation from DVD instructions to install OpenSUSE Leap 15.2 on Simics's QSP using `qsp-dvd-boot.simics` script. Everything works fine except final step - saved after shutdown thru `save-persistent-state` HDD image can't be booted later by `qsp-hdd-boot.script` - UEFI bootloader just passes to PXE and other options and basically hangs.

Is there any way to skip (disable?) PXE, HTTPv4, HTTPv6 and other options and get to the UEFI shell at least? It seems like Simics QSP UEFI can't properly locate ESP which is at /boot/efi/EFI// now, not just /boot/efi/bootx64.efi like in past.

I would really appreciate slim version of Simics UEFI image shipped as well to debug similar circumstances or any instructions on how to build such (is it part of public tianocore?)

BTW, QSP-x86 Target Guide suggest to create a script to boot saved image with some parameters and `qsp-system.include` script - that doesn't work out of the box as `bios_image` should be set as well. I guess using `qsp-hdd-boot.simics` would be simpler and it works after all (given disk0_image=./os-install-final/board.disk0.hd.image.craff).

All of this has been tried at 6.0.84 (6097)

Answer (score 1):

The Simics QSP UEFI is part of the open-source Tianocore. You should be able to build it yourself.

Getting to UEFI shell - press F1 during the boot to get into UEFI menus.